# How to get Internet Speed Android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I need to know my speed Internet which I use in my application:
this's my code :

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        int speedMbps = 0;
        if (wifi.getConnectionInfo() != null) {

                speedMbps = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getLinkSpeed();
        }
```

so speedMbps alwys gives me 64 Mbps even I test my speed internet using a website I found 4,8Mbps so why and where this value 64 comes from ?

Comment: The answer in the question linked already answers your primary question. _where this value 64 comes from ?_ 4.8 Mbps that is shown by speed test websites / apps is your actual throughput (_the Internet connection speed_). Whereas, the 64 Mbps is your WiFi's bandwidth / speed.

Comment: In my case it gives 13Mbps which was nearly equal when i tested it in  (http://www.speedtest.net)

Comment: it's not duplicated !

so my question how to find the real speed ? I don't need philosophy please !

Comment: Bachlet Tansime please remember people help you voluntarily. If they want to give you philosophy then you get philosophy. You can't demand anyone to help you out here.

Comment: @BachletTansime: I am not sure if you read my comment properly. There is nothing philosophical in it. Just a simple explanation of something that is technical. And it is a duplicate. It may be worded differently than your question, but the result is still pretty much the same. And if you don't like it, that is still no reason to be rude. If you believe the question was wrongly closed, you can click the **reopen** button.

Comment: Yes I know, It's my second acount, the first one blocked by the same way, people didn't answer me, and stackovflow Staff had blocked my first account, thank's but Also you did'nt answer me !
 so I found this even it's not what I"m looking for
http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/traffic-statistics-demo-android-tutorial/